# Which GUI toolkit would you use for a touchscreen interface?

Tags: windows, cross-platform, touchscreen, gui-toolkit

The only experience I have so far with a touchscreen interface was one where everything was custom drawn, and I get the feeling it's not the most efficient way of doing it (even the most basic layout change is hell to make). I know plenty of GUI toolkits intended at keyboard & mouse interfaces, but can you advise something suited for touchscreens? Target platform is Windows, but cross-platform would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Windows Presentation Foundation ([WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)). It uses XML ([XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language)) to define the interface and it is therefore quite easy to create an interface which would be easy to use with the touchscreen.

.NET 3.0 required.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Little Caesars, and all orders are handled through the computer system.  They use a touch screen interface which resembles a blown-up version of normal forms.  Buttons are about 20x larger than what you would normally get, and text is enlarged quite a bit as well.  It looked rather simple and I doubt they used a special framework for it.  I recommend you give that a shot, using a standard toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to add Qt as an UI toolkit with (nowadays) solid touch support: [QTouchEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html).

It is also cross-platform for every major platform, which includes embedded devices.